# How to filter records by them amount per date?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have a tablet 'A' that have a column of date. and the same date can be in a few records. I'm trying to filter the records where the amount of the records by day is less than 5. And still keep all the fields of the tablet.

I mean that if i have only 4 records on 11/10/2017 I need to filter all of this 4 records.

Answer (score 1):

So You can SELECT them basing at sub-query . In SUB-Query group them by this date column and then use HAVING with aggregated count to know how many in every date-group we have and then select all which have this count lesser than 5 ;

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
WHERE A.date in (SELECT subA.date 
                   FROM A 
                   GROUP BY A.date 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) < 5 );
```

Comment: Tal, if this answer meets your needs, please mark it as accepted.  That will help future people with similar problems know that this one has been solved, and it will improve your own reputation score.  If you have others you have never accepted, I'd encourage you to go back and look at those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take Care's answer is good.  Alternatively, you can use an analytic/windowing function.  I'd benchmark both and see which one works better.

```
with cte as (
  select *, count(1) over (partition by date) as cnt
  from table_a
)
select *
from cte
where cnt < 5
```

Comment: Your answer is also very clear :P Thanks for showing another way.